# WebView not load images

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to upload my site on an Android WebView, everything works fine except load some pictures that I have on my site.

```
<?
echo $this->Form->create('A');
if($evento['Evento']['habilitar_asientos']){?>
<div id="mapa_tickets" style="width:100%;height:350px;margin-bottom:15px;">
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

<?
if($evento['Evento']['imagen_recinto']){?>
    <image xlink:href="<?echo $evento['Evento']['imagen_recinto'];?>" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" class="base"/>
<?}
foreach ($ticketsActivos as $ticket) {
    if($ticket['Ticket']['imagen_recinto']){?>
        <image xlink:href="<?echo $ticket['Ticket']['imagen_recinto'];?>" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"class="<?echo $ticket['Ticket']['id'];?>"/>
    <?}
}
?>
</svg>
</div>
```

Thus, I am charging my webview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings s = myWebView.getSettings();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://mysite.cl/eventos/evento-completo/inscripciones/seleccion_tickets/");
}
```

In addition, within the site that I am carrying no to pushing buttons that let you keep buying here, but every time I click on a button, it tells me to open the browser and the flow does not follow within the webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this line of code,

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

You can also set these properties..

```
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Give a try to the below code, just paste...

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress == 100)
                    progressBar.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

and
this as an inner class...

```
private class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        progressBar.setProgress(view.getProgress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and i hope you have added the permission as

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```