# WebView setUserAgentString() fails to load images

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I set the user agent in `webView`

```
mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(getString(R.string.str_user_agent));

String : Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1
```

When i set the user agent it fails to load some images. If anyone knows the reason or the answer please mention.

Comment: Do the images load on a PC with a browser with the same user-agent?

Comment: try this answer => [not loaded image in webView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32255056/6364902)

Comment: this link maybe helpful :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727117/android-webview-user-agent-vs-browser-user-agent